# How to Zoom in on a scatter chart, with datetime as x-axis?

Tags: datetime, kendo-ui, zooming, scatter, kendo-dataviz

I see the demo "pan and zoom" http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/scatter-charts/pan-and-zoom.html . However, when I want to zoom in a chart with datetime x-axis, errors come up.
Any one knows how to zoom in with date axis?